# Django PIL: cannot identify image file

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I am trying to open an image and resize it using PIL:

```
     kids = family.kids.all()
     for kid in kids:
            pictureIO = StringIO.StringIO(kid.image_url)
            pictureIO.seek(0)
            im = PIL.Image.open(pictureIO)
            wpercent = (300/float(im.size[0]))
            hsize = int((float(im.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
            im = im.resize((300,hsize), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

But it is giving me error:

```
    cannot identify image file
```

kid.image_url is:

```
   /media/proj/proj/kid1.jpg
```

Traceback:

```
                 im = PIL.Image.open(kid.image_url)
```

How do I resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

StringIO requires a file object, not a filename. Just do:

```
f = open(kid.image_url)
pictureIO = StringIO.StringIO(f)
```

Comment: Thanx for the help i tried this but returns:No such file or directory: '/media/proj/proj/kid1.jpg'

Comment: on f=open(kid.image_url)

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File("/home/sithamparam/Desktop/12.jpg"));
int type = originalImage.getType() == 0 ? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB:originalImage.getType();
BufferedImage resizeImageJpg = resizeImage(originalImage, type);
ImageIO.write(resizeImageJpg, "jpg", new File("/home/sithamparam/Desktop/12.jpg"));
```

Comment: The question is in Python. Your answer is in Java.

Answer (score 0):

URL is "website" related. Use "kid.image.path". (I don't know how your image_url is populated, but I think "/" is based on web root, not drive's one)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/